# Paypal JavaScript SDK with IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using PayPal JavaScript SDK. Now I want to add Instant Payment Notification (IPN) as I have done with just the quick checkout button.
There I have used it in a form with POST like this:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo $HTTP_DIR."method/paypal/ipn.php"; ?>">
```

How I can use "notify_url" with the JS SDK? I did not find it as a parameter.

Is it enough to set up in the PayPal account where I can set an IPN URL?

Answer (score 1):

IPN is a separate 20 year-old system, not needed for current API-based integrations.  Rather than using IPN with that SDK, change to a server-side create/capture with it. Then you'll have an immediate notification of successful payments, with no need to wait for a separate IPN message that may fail.

See the optional bullet #5 of the 'Add and modify the code' section of [Integrate Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/#link-addandmodifythecode), which links to a [demo code sample](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server). You'll just need to create two routes on your PHP server that return JSON, one to create an order when a button is clicked, and the other to capture it after an approval.

Comment: Thank you, I will do it. I have to call a third-party URL to send a curl request. Can I use it in onApprove:
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/' + data.orderID + '/capture/', {
                    method: 'post'
 }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();

And replace the URL with my URL, like in AJAX?
or do I have to use this URL, where does it come from?

Comment: That's the demo app's URL; replace it with your own

Comment: Ok, can I insert there the 'notify_url'?

Comment: No, this is a completely different solution that replaces your existing checkout and does not use IPN.  It requires implementing two routes on your server that call the PayPal REST API to create and capture an order, thus getting an immediate notification of success via that API.  Whatever business logic your IPN listener triggers, should instead be done after a successful capture, right before forwarding the capture response to the calling button JS to show a success message.

Comment: How can I modify the current onApprove function:
 onApprove: function (data, actions) {
                    return actions.order.capture().then(function (orderData) {
                        // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:

to have the URL in the fetch:
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('my_notity_url', {
                    method: 'post'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();

Comment: Try implementing v2/checkout/orders create and capture routes on your server first, and have those endpoints output only JSON.  Then connect them to the createOrder and onApprove functions....

Comment: You won't be using your notify_url anymore. The new create and capture URLs will obsolete it, and be called during the checkout rather than after it.

Comment: I am just using the JS SDK. So far I don't use the REST API. Is that possible?

Comment: Quoting from https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ "If you need to do any server-side operations at order creation time or after payment, such as storing the completed PayPal transaction ID or other order details in your database, a server-based API integration is the most robust solution..."

Comment: A client-side-only JS SDK integration that notifies your server after the fact, offers no security and no reliability. Don't do it. The REST API exists for your use case.

Comment: I will use a file 'approve.php' to capture the approved order and make the REST API call there. I have adjusted the onApprove function but I got an error when paying with paypal that the address is not ok.

I guess this is wrong:
 onApprove: function (data, actions) {
                    var approveUrl = 'dateien/method/paypal/approve.php';
                    return fetch(approveUrl, {
                        method: 'post'
                    }).then(function (orderData) {
                        // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
console.log('Capture result');

Comment: @PrestonPHX The problem with the solution you propose is refunds tracking. Webhooks or IPN are there for paypal initiated communication. You can't have it without setting up IPN or hooks. Oh boy why PayPal dev experience is sooo bad. No match to Stripe...

Comment: When you initiate a refund via API, no webhook is needed as you already receiving an immediate response. If you need to track refund events that occur independent of your API calls (e.g. initiated in www.paypal.com) then of course webhooks exist for exactly this type of use case of events you aren't already receiving API responses for. Don't use IPN.